# extracting key/value info from the view

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have view code that iterates through a filesystem directory that holds images and returns a dictionary with the filenames as keys and filedates as values:

```
def export_dir(request):
    user = request.user
    path = '/Users/darius/Desktop/archive/111715/large/'
    file_arr = os.listdir(path)
    records = {}

    for item in file_arr:
        date = os.stat(os.path.join(path + item)).st_mtime
        filetime = time.ctime(os.stat(os.path.join(path + item)).st_mtime)
        if item.startswith('.'):
            continue

        records[item] = filetime

    variables = RequestContext(request, { 'user': user, 'records': records }) 
    return render_to_response("b5/export.html", variables)
```

how do I extract the data in the template? I’m currently using a custom template filter:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
...
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

and my template tags look like:

```
{% for record in records %}                            
<tr>
    <td>{{ record|get_item:item.filename }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

but I can't get past...

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /export/
Failed lookup for key [item] in "[{'False': False, 'True': True, 'None': None}, {'records': {'3950_14064_9205_042_large_02.jpg': 'Tue Nov 17 22:26:23 2015', '5920_14009_1851_000_large_02.jpg': 'Tue Nov 17 20:14:34 2015', '0520_15129_0015_907_large_02.jpg': 'Tue Nov 17 21:05:22 2015', '4130_10343_2096_016_large_03.jpg': 'Mon Nov 16 17:17:46 2015’,..
```

what is the syntax I need in template to access the dictionary data, or alternatively, how do I need to modify my view code?

Comment: Where do you get `item.filename`? you don't pass any `item`s to the template.

Comment: Just change it to 
{{ record|get_item:record.filename }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting values by key you can just call values() method of your records dict in template

```
{% for file_date in records.values %}                            
<tr>
    <td>{{ file_date }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Or if you need both keys and values use items method

```
{% for file_name, file_date in records.items %}                            
<tr>
    <td>{{ file_date }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no key named `filename` in your dictionary.
You should create a list, something like:

```
records_list = []

for item in file_arr:
    record = {}
    date = os.stat(os.path.join(path + item)).st_mtime
    filetime = time.ctime(os.stat(os.path.join(path + item)).st_mtime)
    if item.startswith('.'):
        continue

    record['filename'] = filename
    record['filedate'] = filetime
    records_list.append(record)
```